# Zend Framework 2 Navigation with Partial

Tags: navigation, partial-views, zend-framework2

I'm using the solution as outlined in this blog post: 
http://adam.lundrigan.ca/2012/07/quick-and-dirty-zf2-zend-navigation/
which is similar to the answer:
[How to set up 2 navigations in zf2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972316/how-to-set-up-2-navigations-in-zf2/12973806#12973806).

However, I'm trying to also use a view partial. When I try to setPartial(), I then get a fatal error:

```
echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu()->setPartial('navigation.phtml');
```

> Fatal error: Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create
>   an instance for menu in
>   /path/to/my/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/AbstractHelper.php
>   on line 471

If I take out setPartial() the navigation renders fine (just not how I want it to look, hence the partial).

Comment: Your path to the partial file might not be setup correctly. See my answer to a question about partial-loops here: [ZF2: where do I store partialLoop template files?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13667272/607410)

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. I have the navigation.phtml file at the root of the view folder under the Application module. If I change the parameter path to setPartial() in any way I then get an error about it not being able to find the script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your view:

```
$partial = array('myfolder/navigation.phtml', 'default');
$this->navigation('navigation')->menu()->setPartial($partial);

echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu()->render();
```